# Bell's theorem and Fourier components

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bells-inequality

I'm looking for the error in the following because it is impossible :

Bell set up the classical covariance :

$$C(a,b)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}A(a,x)B(b,x)dx$$

Now it should have the following properties : $C(a,a)=-1$, to depend only on relative angle : $C(a,b)=C(a-b)$ and finally to be quantum $|3C(\pi/4)-C(3\pi/4)|>2$

Consider the following formulas :

Take $B=-A$ and $A(a,x)=f(a-x)$.
Then we consider 2 components of the Fourier transform :

$$f(x)=E\cos(\alpha x)+F\cos(\beta x)$$

Putting in the integration using $\cos(a-b)=\cos a\cos b+\sin a\sin b$ the orthogonality of cosine functions when $\alpha\neq \beta\in\mathbb{N}^*$ :

$$C(a,b)=\frac{E^2}{2}\cos(\alpha(a-b))+\frac{F^2}{2}\cos(\beta(a-b))$$

The conditions above are $E=-F=1$

Choosing $\alpha=3,\beta=4$ gives $C(\pi/4)=(-1-1/\sqrt{2})/2,C(3\pi/4)=(1/\sqrt{2}-1)/2$

Giving as CHSH value $1+\sqrt{2}>2$ which is impossible ?

Comment: It's because it lacks the $|f(x)|<1$ condition.